# What's a more specific definition of timeit(), or what does it do?

Tags: python, methods, timeit

I've run the code below (added nested functions on purpose just to make it clear what timeit does) and the result is always something like 0.000 ....

According to the docs this method measures the execution time. Now of course if I run the code as a normal function outside the ''' ''', it would crash.

So what, then, is timeit actually measuring?? If the below function was to run just once, say twice, it would deplete all the resources.

```
import timeit

mycode = '''
def example():
    list = []
    for x in range(0, 100):
        for y in range(0,11111):
            for z in range(0,99999):
                list.append(x)
                list.append(y)
                list.append(z)
'''

print(timeit.timeit(
    stmt=mycode,
    number=10000
))
```

Comment: You're not actually *running* `example`, just defining it 10000 times.

Comment: Just to note, an extremely aggressive compiler could also recognize that nothing ever *uses* the list (your function never returns it), and optimize it away.

Comment: @chepner What do you mean by aggressive compiler? How would it optimise it?

Comment: `example` returns `None`, and nothing inside the function uses the value of `list` or modifies any external state. The function `def example(): pass` is equivalent, aside from using less CPU time.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica So it only measures how long  it takes to define it? Basically how long it takes to read through all the bits?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica is correct, it just defines a function 10000 times. But also, the beauty of open source software, is you can actually read exactly what it does. See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/63298930fb531ba2bb4f23bc3b915dbf1e17e9e1/Lib/timeit.py

Comment: @RyanSandridge yes, i've read that before, but didn't get it, hence i asked here.